# SQL GroupBy unorder my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
UserId   Messagge   Date

1        Hi         2013-01-01
1        Bye        2013-02-01
3        Hi         2013-01-01
2        Hi2        2013-01-02
2        Hi3        2013-01-02
```

I need the list of users' messages in the same order they wrote it. But the SQL Query:

```
select DISTINCT t.UserId from (select UserId,Date from Messages) as t
```

Returns:

```
1
2
3
```

I can't order the subquery by Date and, anyway, if i try to do a Distinct over a query the users' id are always ordered.

I need a SQL Query that returns:

```
1
3
2
```

The order in which users wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select userid
from (
   select userid, 
          min(date) as min_date
   from messages
   group by userid
) t
order by min_date
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/015ff/1

Btw: `date` is  a horrible name for a column. First because it's also a reserved keyword, secondly because it doesn't document it's intent. Is is a "posting date", an "edit date", a "delete date", a "publish date" or something completely different?

Comment: "Date" is the name for the example. Actually, the column's name is 'Publish_Date' ;) Thx